# Object is not moving in opengles

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am newbie in opengles I have created EAGLView class code is give below
I am added following method in EAGLView class

```
- (void)updateScene:(CGPoint)delta {
   float f=delta.x;
NSLog(@"%f",f);
glLoadIdentity(); 
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(f,0.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();



/////////
}
```

I want to move object when user touches the screen ,code of touch method is gives below which is in controller

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.eaglView];

[eaglView updateScene:touchLocation];
}
```

Comment: **Please read this,
it is the answer to your future gl questions too:** Click [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your code you are pushing matrix, do transform and then pop the matrix. But there is no drawing. Do it like this:

```
- (void)updateScene:(CGPoint)delta {
   float f=delta.x;
   NSLog(@"%f",f);
   glLoadIdentity(); 
   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(f,0.0, 0.0);
   //draw something here
   glPopMatrix();
}
```

And BTW: you have to convert view coords to the normalized device coords (which are in range [-1..1] for both x and y).

Comment: how to convert touch coordinates to device coords(-1,1);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611468/in-opengl-es-how-do-i-convert-screen-coordinates-to-world-coordinates